# XSLT only output part of a node in certain conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I often get some XML that isn't formatted as I'm expecting it to be, and am looking for the best way to automatically fix it. Unfortunately, the solution is skating over my head.

I'm working on magazine content, and having difficult with two specific elements.

```
There are <subhead> elements, and <body> elements. Even though the subhead element should always be on it's own, sometimes the proofer will accidentally nest it with a <body> node.

<subhead> nodes should be formatted as their own paragraph, wrapped in <p> and <strong> tags.

<body> nodes should just be wrapped in <p> tags.

So I could get either:
<subhead>Dogs</subhead>
<body>Dogs do not like cats.</body>
or
<body><subhead>Dogs</subhead> Dogs do not like cats.</body>

I would like either scenario to output as:
<p><strong>Dogs</strong></p>
<p>Dogs do not like cats.</p>
```

Currently, my code looks like..

```
<xsl:for-each select="//default:textObject/default:text/*">
<xsl:for-each select="./*">

<xsl:choose>

<xsl:when test="@name='subhead'">
<p><strong>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</strong></p>
</xsl:when>

<xsl:when test="@name='body'">
<p>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</p>
</xsl:when>

...

</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

How can I adjust this accordingly to solve that problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Please review your question - judging by how it reads, and the sudden bold text, I'm guessing you tried to insert tags and it didn't quite end up as you intended. As such, it's hard to work out what you mean re: the incoming XML structure, which is vital for anyone trying to answer XSLT questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This short and simple, complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="(subhead | body/subhead)/text()"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="body/text()"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="subhead/text()">
  <p><strong><xsl:value-of select="."/></strong></p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="body/text()">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
    <subhead>Dogs</subhead>
    <body>Dogs do not like cats.</body>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted result:**

```
<p><strong>Dogs</strong></p>
<p>Dogs do not like cats.</p>
```

**When the same transformation is applied to a document of the second type:**

```
<t>
    <body><subhead>Dogs</subhead> Dogs do not like cats.</body>
</t>
```

**again the same wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<p><strong>Dogs</strong></p>
<p> Dogs do not like cats.</p>
```

**Explantion**:

The order in which the results of particular templates appear in the output depends not on the order of the matched nodes, but on the order of the respective `<xsl:apply-templates>` instructions that cause the templates to be selected for execution.

**Do note**:

In case the structure of the document is *really* unknown, simply replace in the above code:

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="(subhead | body/subhead)/text()"/>
```

with:

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="(//subhead | //body/subhead)/text()"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's generally inadvisable to attempt to code XSLT for an unpredictable incoming data structure. What if other nesting errors occur? Your time would be better spent adding in a layer of validation. In its simplest form this might just be a DTD/Schema sheet that the proofer has to run their XML through.

To answer your question nonetheless, try this. I have assumed each `body`/`subhead` pairing is inside a common element (`item`), but you didn't say. (Otherwise, where `subhead` tags are by themselves, how do you know which `subhead` relates to which `body` - is it always the preceding/following sibling?)

**XML**

```
<root>
    <item>
        <subhead>Dogs</subhead>
        <body>Dogs do not like cats.</body>
    </item>
    <item>
        <body><subhead>Dogs</subhead> Dogs do not like cats.</body>
    </item>
</root>
```

**XSL:**

```
<!-- root and static content -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select='root/item/body' />
</xsl:template>

<!-- iteration content - subhead/body pairings (matching 'body' nodes) -->
<xsl:template match='body'>
    <p><strong><xsl:value-of select='parent::*/subhead | subhead' /></strong></p>
    <p><xsl:value-of select='text()' /></p>
</xsl:template>
```

You can run it at [this XMLPlayground session](http://www.xmlplayground.com/PL5F7N).